# How can the value of a SubFactory be set when creating a Factory object

Tags: python, django, factory, factories

Is it possible to set a value of a SubFactory without creating two Factory objects?

For example, I've got two Factories;

```
class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = 'mysite.user'

    name = "Mark"


class MyFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = 'mysite.myfactory'

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
```

And I want to create `MyFactory()` and at the same time set the value of `user.name`.

Do you have to create `user = UserFactory.create(name="John")` first or can it all be done in a one-liner from the args to `MyFactory()`?

At the moment in a test I've got the following;

```
def setUp(self):
    user = factories.UserFactory(name="John")
    myfactory = factories.MyFactory(user=user)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=subfactory#calling), you can define `SubFactory` fields right in the external factory definition:

```
factories.MyFactory(user__name="John")
```

Hope that helps.